# How would I go about parsing a text file of thousands of DNA bases?

Tags: python, parsing, formatting

Here's what I would have, I would have a massive text file of a bunch of dna bases (A, T, C, G) and what I would like to do is take every 60 characters (arbitrary) and put it on a new line so that way the bases get separated out in chunks. But, I would also like for there to be overlap of each chunk by a certain number of bases. For example, if this 10 letter chunk ATGGCTGCTA was given, and the initial 4 block chunk was ATGG, if there overlap parameter was specified to be 2, then the next 4 block chunk would be GGCT, then CTGC and so on. I know I'll probably have to look into reading, opening, and writing text files with python. If any has resources they could point me torwards on achieving this and any tips and instructions that would be great.

Example of the formatting of the text I would be working with:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_000017.11?report=fasta&from=7661779&to=7687550

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: What exactly should the output look like (givem a relatively short sample of the input)? I think you should add both to your question.

Comment: I think nosklo has the idea of what I want. I just need to figure out how to make general now (IE the parameters can be input by whoever is using the program) which doesn't seem to hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = 'GAGACAGAGTCTCACTCTGTTGCACAGGCTGGAGTGCAGTGGCACAATCTCTGCTCACTGCAACCTCCTC'
chunk_size = 5
overlap = 2

for pos in range(0, len(data), chunk_size - overlap):
    print(data[pos:pos+chunk_size])
```

The results:

```
GAGAC
ACAGA
GAGTC
TCTCA
CACTC
TCTGT
...
```

Comment: so according to python docs the you're essentially using three parameters in the range function which would be start, stop and step if I'm not mistaken. thank you so much for this!

Comment: @martineau i was trying to find a way to do that but I don't see a button or anything for that is it the check mark?