# Why isn't my text parsing correctly?

Tags: python, parsing, formatting

Follow up referring to this question I asked earlier: [How would I go about parsing a text file of thousands of DNA bases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845282/how-would-i-go-about-parsing-a-text-file-of-thousands-of-dna-bases)

Here's the simple code I wrote to handle the text files:

```
g = open('EGFRsequencencbidata.txt', 'r')
f = open('data.txt', 'w+')
data = g.read()
oligo_size = int(input("oligo size: "))
overlap = int(input("overlap size: "))
for pos in range(0, len(data), oligo_size - overlap):
    f.write(data[pos:pos+oligo_size] + '\n')
f.close()
g.close()
```

Based on what I got from "nosklo" (guy who answered my question) I was able to produce results that mirrored his up to a certain point. However, my code doesn't seem to produce the line by line results I want after about 22 or so lines like so. It starts truncating lines instead of them all being the same size.

[example of what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EnSs.png)

I want all of them to be for example 5 characters long (oligo_size parameter).

Anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: Does the file contains spaces? Or new lines?

Comment: Nevertheless, this code is not well suited for large files, since it loads the entire file into memory.

Comment: Can you share (a part) of your sample file?

Comment: I beg you to scrap the input() call from the example - there are so many ways you can structure your code without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file may contain white space.

```
data = g.read()
data = data.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: thank you! I ended up figuring out that white space, new lines, breaks and all that stuff was the issue and just replaced it all with "".